# How to change the color of the item being selected in md-select in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am using the dark theme in angular-material 1.0.4. This is how the select element looks like when selecting an item:

[image: Selecting item in dark theme]

And this is how it looks like when using the default theme:

[image: Selecting item in default theme]

The dark theme doesn't handle the color very well. How can I change the background color of the item being selected (light grey on the pictures), or the color of the text of the item?

I use only the default css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-material/angular-material.css">
```

And this is the definition of the select:

```
        <md-input-container flex="30">
            <label>Branch</label>
            <md-select ng-model="selectedBranch">
                <md-option ng-repeat="b in branches" value="{{b.id}}">
                    {{b.name}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
```

And this is how I initialise the dark theme:

```
app.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .dark()
        .primaryPalette('orange')
        .accentPalette('yellow')
        .warnPalette('deep-orange');
});
```

**NOTE:** The problem is not solved using a colour on mouse hover, because the item can be selected by keyboard as well.

---

**EDIT:** In the end, the answer was all about figuring out that the event, which colours the text, is "focus".

Comment: please put your code so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
md-option:focus{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
md-option:hover{
  color: black; 
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
md-option ._md-text{
 color:green;
}
```

or (depends on version)

```
md-option .md-text{
        color:green;
}
```

selector+icon :

```
md-select ._md-text{
        color:white;
}

//drop down icon : 
md-select ._md-text{display:inline}._md-select-value ._md-select-icon{
        color: white;
}
```